# How to add an assert to an if ..else condition

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to put if else condition in assert statement

I have tried this but not working
I need to verify two string one by one

```
String comment = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='historyRow']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")).getText();
        System.out.println(comment);
        if (comment == "abc") {
            Assert.assertEquals(comment, "abc");
        }
        else{
            Assert.assertEquals(comment, "xy");
        }
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Details")).click();
```

Comment: are you trying to compare the values of comment and "abc"? If so, why asserting on what you already know?

Comment: @Mate Mrše  Just info: by origin post, `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Details")).click();` not inside `else` block.

Comment: you could wrap your assertions with [try-catch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148123/3355860)

Comment: @Stultuske I am trying to verify two different String with assertion If first string is "abc" then verify first String and if it is "xyz" then verify second string

Comment: How can I verify that in comment object "abc" string is there or "xyz" string is there?

Comment: if ( "abc".equals(comment)) { } else if ( "xyz".equals(comment)) { } You shouldn't use asserts like that in business code, rather in tests

Comment: @frianH Sorry, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

You're using == to compare Strings. Since Strings are objects, this checks if both sides refer to the exact same object. If you wish to check if the Strings value is equal, use:

`"abc".equals(comment)`

Answer (score 2):

It seem like you want compare with `or` condition, I suggest to use `.assertTrue`.

Use `.equals()` to compare string not `==`.

```
String comment = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='historyRow']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")).getText();

boolean condition = false;
if(comment.equals("abc") || comment.equals("xy")) {
    condition = true;
}

Assert.assertTrue(condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Which library are you using for assertion?
Here is how you can assert if string equals one of several with junit:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "xyz";
String s3 = "https://junit.org";
Assert.assertThat( s1, AnyOf.anyOf( IsEqual.equalTo( "abc" ), IsEqual.equalTo( "xyz" ) ) ); // passed
Assert.assertThat( s2, AnyOf.anyOf( IsEqual.equalTo( "abc" ), IsEqual.equalTo( "xyz" ) ) ); // passed
Assert.assertThat( s3, AnyOf.anyOf( IsEqual.equalTo( "abc" ), IsEqual.equalTo( "xyz" ) ) ); // failed
```

Another way to the same assert you can use with both junit and testNG:

```
Assert.assertTrue(s1.matches( "abc|xyz" )); // passed
Assert.assertTrue(s2.matches( "abc|xyz" )); // passed
Assert.assertTrue(s3.matches( "abc|xyz" )); // failed
```

The difference is in the fail messages.

The first:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected: ("abc" or "xyz")
>        but: was "https://junit.org"

And the second - just empty assertion error.

> 